# Add a select list to the content of the view

Tags: 7, views

Could we add a select list in a view content?

I have below view and I want to add a select list that has (Approve and Reject items) for each row under 'Status' column. Also, there will be a 'Save' button to save the changes in database.

[image]

Can we do this in view or there is another way? Please help..

Comment: You can take global php variable in the fields section in your views and in that provide two links one with the name approve and another with the name reject and define custom menu for each link in hook_menu and define the menu callbacks for them where you can programmatically save the content.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. If I add this to global php <a href='URL'>More Info...</a> what is the URL that I have to add it??

Comment: hook_menu.. Can I alter the view module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read post [Programmatically Creating Forms with Views in Drupal 7](https://www.isovera.com/blog/programmatically-creating-forms-views-drupal-7) which is very close to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. It is a useful link but they use a custom module.. Can I customize view module by using this function 'views_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args)' ??

Comment: Hacking a contributed module is not allowed in Drupal because you don't know your code may break the default functionality of the module or some dependent module.

Instead hacking contributed module you can write custom field handler in your custom module.